How to fix error on react Route component render using wrapper-component?
I have basic reactjs app and I want to implement kind of is authenticated check. So if user is authenticated, he can access pages, of not user must be redirected to /login.
here is rootes configuration
export const privateRoutes: Array<RouteType> = [
    {
        path: '/users',
        element: UsersPage,
        exact: true,
    }
];

export const publicRoutes: Array<RouteType> = [
    {
        path: '/login',
        element: LoginPage,
        exact: true,
    },
];

I created Route wrapper which checks authentication:
interface PrivateRouteProps {
    key: number,
    path: string;
    element: React.ReactNode;
}

const PrivateRoute: FC<PrivateRouteProps> = ({key, path, element}) => {
    const {userIsAuthenticated, hasPermission} = usePermission();

    return (
        <Route
            path={path}
            element={userIsAuthenticated() ? element : <Navigate to="/login" />}
        />
    );
};

and here is routing service:
export const RouterService: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <SecurityProvider>
                <Routes>
                    {privateRoutes.map((route: RouteType, index: number) => (
                        <PrivateRoute
                            key={index}
                            path={route.path}
                            element={<Layout>
                                <route.element/>
                            </Layout>}
                        />
                    ))}
                    {publicRoutes.map((route: RouteType, index: number) => (
                        <PrivateRoute
                            key={index}
                            path={route.path}
                            element={<BaseLayout>
                                <route.element/>
                            </BaseLayout>}
                        />
                    ))}
                </Routes>
            </SecurityProvider>
        </Router>
    );

In browser console I get:
history.ts:494 Uncaught Error: [PrivateRoute] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

What I'm doing wrong and how to implement this functionality properly?

What React Router needs inside Routes is a <Route /> element. Your wrapping breaks that pattern.
So you need something like the below:
export const RouterService: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <SecurityProvider>
                <Routes>
                    {privateRoutes.map((route: RouteType, index: number) => (
                        <Route
                            key={index}
                            path={route.path}
                            element={YOUR_ELEMENT_HERE}
                        />
                    ))}
                </Routes>
            </SecurityProvider>
        </Router>
    );

YOUR_ELEMENT_HERE can be replaced by the PrivateRoute HOC you have created.
You can do something like:
const PrivateRoute: FC<PrivateRouteProps> = ({key, path, children}) => {
    const {userIsAuthenticated, hasPermission} = usePermission();

    if(!userIsAuthenticated()) <Navigate to="/login" />;

    return <>{children}</>;
};


And then replace YOUR_ELEMENT_HOC with this pattern
<PrivateRoute>
 <UsersPage />
</PrivateRoute>

To make things dynamic you can transform your array of these elements.
There is also this mechanism of using Outlets to do this. Which will make it much easier.
The idea being, you keep top level elements which act as slots (outlets), inside which nested components are rendered. Your whole logic of authentication is in one place.
The pattern used is like this:
const PrivateRouteWrapper: FC<PrivateRouteProps> = ({key, path, element}) => {
    const {userIsAuthenticated, hasPermission} = usePermission();
    if(!userIsAuthenticated()) <Navigate to="/login" />; 

   return <Outlet />

};

and the routes
 <Router>
            <SecurityProvider>
                <Routes>
                 <Route element={<PrivateRoutesWrapper/>}>
                   {/* map your Routes inside */}
                </Routes>
            </SecurityProvider>
        </Router>

